# Incorrect syntax near ',' - possibly related to calc syntax error

Tags: string, sql-server-2012, calc

When I use the code below (with a select statement and other fields listed prior), it throws an "Incorrect syntax near ','." exception for the line marked ,Working Capital.  I suspect that there is something wrong with the Calculation that I am using for the EBIYDA calc.  Please help.

----ENTITY TOTALS----------

```
[MPSA-TotRev] as TotalComp,
EBITDACalc = (Comp.VariableComp - (Comp.VariableComp * 1-AdjGMPercent)) - ([FixedCosts]-(Comp.[FixedComp]),
------Balance Sheet Metrics--------
WorkingCapital
```

Answer (score 1):

Close the parenthesis you opened before FixedCosts in your EBITCalc.